# How do you convert a package into a Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

My Spring Boot app won't start and it gives this exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'setupIdsClient' defined in com.spinsci.ssodemo.SSODemoApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cisco.ccbu.common.ids.client.IdSClient]: Factory method 'setupIdsClient' threw exception; nested exception is **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonSyntaxException**

I believe it's because of this SDK:

https://developer.cisco.com/docs/contact-center-express/#!cisco-identity-service-client-sdk

I can't use the one with dependencies because then it complains about another error (`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;`). I believe the packaged dependencies are out of date or conflict with Spring Boot. I want to package the dependencies myself with the Maven `pom.xml`.

How do I specify the artifact and group to use? I searched for `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException` on https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Crepository but it only gave me 2 results `com.jwebmp` and `com.jwebmp.jre10` which doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I had to prepend `fc:` for a full class search:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

It still turns up some questionable results but I found the right one.